# sprintf not doing anything - trying to output as two digit number (leading zero)

Tags: php, printf

I have a seconds to time function and I want to always output minutes and seconds values as two digits. In other words `5` would become `05`. I used `sprintf` in the function, but it is not doing anything.  The values are still being returned as single digits.

```
//convert seconds to time
function convertSeconds($seconds)
{
    // extract hours
    $hours = floor($seconds / (60 * 60));

    // extract minutes
    $divisor_for_minutes = $seconds % (60 * 60);
    $minutes = floor($divisor_for_minutes / 60);

    // extract the remaining seconds
    $divisor_for_seconds = $divisor_for_minutes % 60;
    $seconds = ceil($divisor_for_seconds);

    // return the final array
    $obj = array(
        "h" => (int) $hours,
        "m" => (int) sprintf("%02d", $minutes),
        "s" => (int) sprintf("%02d", $seconds)
    );
    return $obj;
}
```

Comment: You have to remove `(int)` typecasting if you want have output in 2-digit format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's problem with casting you are casting of `sprint()` not variables so try

```
$obj = array(
        "h" => (int)$hours,
        "m" => sprintf("%02d", (int)$minutes),
        "s" => sprintf("%02d", (int)$seconds)
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

The `sprintf` function will format a number correctly if you remove the casting to integer:

```
$obj = array(
    "h" => (int) $hours,
    "m" => sprintf("%02d", $minutes),
    "s" => sprintf("%02d", $seconds)
);
```

In the decimal representation integer cannot start with a zero (only hexadecimal, octal and binary representations of integers can start with a zero).